# Where can I find a list of recent updates from Microsoft?

Tags: windows-update

What I would like to find is a list of all the recent updates, and when they were released.

Products such as MS Office, Windows, MSSQL, etc.

Only way I know to get a list of updates, is to go to the update page, and it only shows me ones I do not have.

That and this is to assist a friend who I can not see their list of updates. I just need to know if a recent update could address their issue. (Not going to install updates blindly).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wouldn't Microsofts technet site be the place to look?
I had a quick look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin
Although its broken down a bit into categories it should show you what you're asking for

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: List is not always upto date?

Answer (score 2):

Since Microsoft switched to rollup updates, here's the list:

Windows 7: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009469/windows-7-sp1-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-update-history

Windows 10: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4018124/windows-10-update-history

---

<s>You can get a list of all security and non-security updates by date here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/894199/en-us</s>

Unfortunately, this appears to be gone now. But if you need older updates you can still view the historical version of the page via the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160316134643/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/894199

That link points to the current year, and seems to update automatically. To view previous years, go down to the bottom and you'll find a list of links.

Joe's link to the Technet security centre focuses more on security updates; I'm not sure if it shows the non-security ones at all.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @RichardPeck Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bunch:

http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?s=60c91e51d4969c47a3deb749dce00b5c&autocom=downloads