# Where can I get a list of Microsoft KB #'s and corresponding update descriptions?

Tags: windows-update

I realize [Microsoft has a searchable databse](http://support.microsoft.com/search/?adv=1), but I don't want to have to plug in all 150,000 KB entries so that I can update my Excel spreadsheet.  Is there somewhere that already has these listed?  Something that I can cut and paste so that I can later use a query for Windows update descriptions that apply to our security audit?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin.  Funny how I was able to find this by doing a Google Search https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=microsoft+kb+updates+list&oq=microsoft+kb+updates+list and it was the very first result.

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: @Raystafarian - Does it matter? The website I linked to lists update for every single Microsoft product.

Comment: @Ramhound Just because you found it on the first round doesn't mean I didn't attmept a google search my self several times over.  Theres thousands of search terms you could use, you just happen the correct ones.  Actually adding this as an answer would be helpful as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @hydroparadise - This isn't the first time this question has been asked on this website http://superuser.com/questions/118789/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-recent-updates-from-microsoft

Comment: http://kbupdate.info/

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of every single product update and its description for a specific product at Microsoft's [Security TechCenter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security) website.  There are other features including being sent an email when security updates are released and an RSS feed..

The direct link to the list of Bulletins is [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin)

Comment: At first glance, the answer provided looked like what I need.  However, giving a closer look, it looks like there's information missing. I was looking up kb2808679 in the table, but sorting the Excel spreadsheet by KB revealed that it jumps from kb2807986 to kb2809279.  Thanks for you trying to be helpful though.

Comment: @hydroparadise - This indicates that `kb2808679` either does not exist or is connected to a different product then your looking up.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2808679/en-us

Comment: @hydroparadise - The update was released for multiple operating system.  It might not show up in a "all product" search.